# add name field with email to invite block

Tags: users

I want to capture the name of the user who is invited by an existing user, along with the conventional email field. This is because I want to use this name in the email that is sent to invited user so that he finds his own name on top of the mail bosy as "Dear 'name'" .

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly positive if this is what you're asking, so if I misunderstood the question, just let me know.

You can add any field you want to the user registration forms if you go right here on your site: /admin/config/people/accounts/fields

So even though there are not any 'First name' or 'Last name' fields by default, you can add anything you want and then get to those fields through views...

Does that help?